# Encoding a URL string according to RFC 1738 using JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to send a request to Twitter through my Angular JS application, and Twitter's API requires that you encode the consumer key and secret according to RFC 1738. Is there a javascript function built to do this?

As a heads-up, I know that RFC 3986 is newer and obsoletes 1738, but the Twitter API asks specifically for RFC 1738 so I figured I should try to do that to avoid possibly getting screwed over by a corner case. For clarification, I'm talking about part 1 of the "Issuing application-only requests" section on this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

**NOTE: I have copied the question from another one but that ones is for the GO language. My case is with JS**

Comment: `escape` [should *partly* follow 1738](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.2.1), but I guess twitter API will also accept `encodeURIComponent`, closer to 3986.